# What does a symmetrical explosion mean in the context of preventing accidental nuclear weapon trigger?

Tags: nuclear-physics, symmetry, nuclear-engineering, explosions

I just watched a video entitled [This Is the Real Risk We Face with Nuclear Weapons](https://www.facebook.com/veritasium/videos/1728062757701878/). In the video, it referenced a "broken arrow" incident where a US B-52 was carrying a nuclear weapon met with an accident. The weapon fell to the ground causing the conventional explosives contained in it to partially detonate, hence failing to trigger the fission and thereafter the fusion reaction.

At 3:15, according to the video, in order to trigger the fission part of the reaction, the conventional explosion must be symmetrical. I presume that means all conventional explosives need to go off at once? Or any combination of explosives that are symmetrical in shape?

Is this a deliberate design or is this limited by nuclear physics?

Comment: Scott Manley has a series of videos on the design of nuclear weapons. He goes through this. [Going Nuclear](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?app=desktop&list=PLtivPPQQIsb5yc-tg1VuHd3vv2DkOr-rB)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this a deliberate design or is this limited by nuclear physics ?

It is both. A major challenge in nuclear weapons design is holding a critical mass of fissile material together for long enough to generate a maximum yield of energy. Once critical mass is achieved, the heat and pressure generated tends to scatter the fissile material, resulting in a [fizzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizzle_(nuclear_explosion)). One common solution to this problem is to enclose the fissile material in a shell of [explosive lenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosive_lens) which are detonated to create an imploding spherical shock wave. This shock wave concentrates the fissile material past its critical density and also holds it together long enough to maximise the yield of the weapon. The detonation of the explosive lenses must be very precisely timed in order to produce a sufficiently symmetrical shock wave. So the accidental detonation of one or more lenses will result in a large conventional explosion and contamination of the immediate area (as happened in the [1966 Palomares B-52 crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1966_Palomares_B-52_crash)), but will not produce a full nuclear explosion.

Comment: IDK how many people know just what is inside the "physics package" of made-in-the-USA nuclear weapons, but it's conceivable that there could be a self-destruct system that would initiate asymmetric detonation of the lens if some unauthorized person tried to force the thing open. I guess it would depend on which they thought was worse; the risk of an accidental self-destruct, and the resulting damage and contamination, or the risk of the technology falling in to the wrong hands. Who knows? Maybe the "broken arrow" to which OP referred was a self-destruct activation. ISTR, it made a _big_ mess.

Comment: But that doesn't answer why the explosive shell has to be symmetrical eg. a sphere? Why can't it be a asymmetrical shape, eg. an eggshape? Would a shell of such a shape fail to detonate the device entirely?

Comment: @dazzleworth The explosive shell itself does not have to be spherical. It consists of multiple shaped charges, often arranged in the form of a regular polyhedron, often using two different explosives - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosive_lens for a cut-away diagram. It is the resulting implosion shock wave that has to be spherical, and achieving this symmetry in an environment that is fundamentally non-linear is the difficult part.

Comment: In fact, the "primary" of the US-made [W88 warhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W88) is said to be "egg shaped."

Comment: @SolomonSlow - the so-called 'oblate primary'.